# If you buy a physical Switch title, is it region-locked?

Tags: nintendo-switch

If I buy a physical copy of a Nintendo Switch game, will I only be able to play it in the language/locale of that physical copy? Or does owning that copy grant me the ability to play it in ALL language / region settings?

I heard that the Switch is region-free, but I also know there can always be fine-print.

Comment: "but we recommend that players buy games within their region to ensure full service and support." See, it is not a duplicate question, because nobody has explained what "full service and support" means. Again, no guarantee that end user will not get screwed by some loophole. Someone please explain what that means!

Comment: It means like updates and game service. Say, you buy a game from japan and it breaks. It will be real hard to get support for it!

Comment: If you found an answer to the question, feel free to post it on the question this was closed as a duplicate of. That way we can keep all the information in the same place.

Comment: @Wrigglenite I have found a solution to my problem, but that solution still does not *answer* my original question. I do not presume that my solution will be a solution for all who have the same question. That's why I included this as an **update** to my question instead of an answer... until you deleted my edit. I don't think your deletion of my edit will be helpful to others. Quite the contrary.

Comment: That's why I'm asking you to post your solution as an answer, if it can help people. It is not part of the problem, so it should not be in the question.

Comment: @Wrigglenite Please reread the wording: "Does owning that copy grant me the ability to play it in ALL language / region settings" ... my solution does not answer this question. It avoids the physical format entirely. Anyone committed to collecting physical copies will not find my solution viable, as I ultimately chose the digital download format instead.